# Distinct by order date and products SQL Server 2008

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008

This is my first post here so if I've been mistaken for my post and English I say sorry :)

I already do research in google and unfortunately until now I can't solve this.

This my problem, show the total orders by date on each product and I want to distinct by products

Here's my query sample

```
SELECT Orders.OrderDate
          ,SUM(OrderDetails.OrderDetailQuantity) AS totalOrdered
          ,Products.ProductId 
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId 
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductId = Products.ProductId 
GROUP BY Orders.OrderId
          ,Orders.OrderDate
          ,Products.ProductId 
HAVING (CONVERT(VARCHAR,  Orders.OrderDate, 23) BETWEEN @from AND @to)
```

Now, I want to distinct by product according to the between OrderDate, I know the big problem here is the DATE but I don't have any idea on how to distinct the date by this query.

Please help me. Thank you.

P.S.: if do you want to solve this in linq expression it would be highly accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data and desired results would help.  When you say "distinct by" I assume you mean group by.  Note, in the WHERE clause you dont need to cast Order.OrderDate if you ensure that the time component of your @from & @to params are set correctly (to include each entire day). Its never a good idea to apply a cast operation to the left side of a comparison.

```
SELECT  --cast(Orders.OrderDate as date),
        Products.ProductId 
        SUM(OrderDetails.OrderDetailQuantity) AS totalOrdered,
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId 
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductId = Products.ProductId 
where Orders.OrderDate between cast(@from as date) AND cast(@to as date)
GROUP 
BY      --cast(Orders.OrderDate as date),
        Products.ProductId 


-- to illustrate:
declare @From datetime = '1/1/2000 10:30:22',
        @To datetime = '1/3/2000 9:11:31'

declare @orders table (i int, dt datetime)
insert into @orders
    values(1, '1/1/2000 8:00'),(2, '1/2/2000 10:00'), (3, '1/4/2000 3:00')


-- only returns i=2
select *
from    @orders
where dt between @From and @To

-- returns i=1 & i=2
select *
from    @orders
where dt between cast(@From as date) and cast(@To as date)
```

Comment: yes is that correct, but i don't want show the column OrderDate so i can easily to group by the products.. thank for your reply sir :)

Comment: What should the final result look like? Just two columns ProductId and totalOrdered ?

Comment: yes sir, thats what i want to show.. but we know that we need to group by the OrderDate so we can filter by between date..

Comment: You dont need to select OrderDate to group by it.  Likewise, you dont need to group by OrderDate to filter on it.

Comment: yes sir i got your point.. my problem is i want to get the totalQuantity by each product.. in the range of OrderDate(from to to)