# How to select rows with distinct column value ordered by date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have this table:

```
create table #tmp
(
  column1 varchar(3),
  column2 varchar(5),
  column3 datetime,
  column4 int
)

insert into #tmp values ('AAA', 'SKA', '2013-02-01 00:00:00', 10)
insert into #tmp values ('AAA', 'SKA', '2013-01-31 00:00:00', 15)
insert into #tmp values ('AAA', 'SKB', '2013-01-31 00:00:00', 20)
insert into #tmp values ('AAA', 'SKB', '2013-01-15 00:00:00', 5)
insert into #tmp values ('AAA', 'SKC', '2013-02-01 00:00:00', 25)
```

I want to select rows with distinct column2, ordered by column3.
This is the desired result:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3                       Col4
AAA   SKB    2013-01-15 00:00:00.000    5
AAA   SKA    2013-01-31 00:00:00.000    15
AAA   SKC    2013-02-01 00:00:00.000    25
```

How can I do that?
I'm using MS SQL 2005 and 2008

Comment: How do you determine which of the 2 `SKA` records is the correct one to return?

Comment: @alroc: By date, I want the oldest one.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455233/distinct-by-order-date-and-products-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
;with cte as 
(
  select *, 
  row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 
             order by column3) rnk
  from #tmp

) select * from cte where rnk = 1
  order by column3;
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a5a9/8)

Comment: This would not work if col1,col2,col3 values are duplicated in more than one row. Better to use `row_number()` [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea54e/1)  not distinct

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3dad/11

select * from
(
select max(column1) as column1, column2 as column2, max(column3) as column3, 
  max(column4) as column4
from #tmp
group by column2
) a
order by column3
```

Comment: this query will not work. It has many syntax errors and not complete

Comment: sorry i missed the additional fields in the group by. it should work now

Comment: you forgot to add alias for subquery. This will not return desired output though

Comment: ok i finally ran on sql fiddle and posted the running script !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.  You have to handle the other columns.

From that exact data, to get that exact result:

```
select column1, column2, min(column3), min(column4)
from #tmp
group by column1, column2
```

However, in general the column3 value might be from a different record than the column4 value, and as written in the SQL, if you have more than one column1 value with the same column2 value, you will get more than one result with the same column2.

Comment: Column1 will always have the same value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.column1, t.column2, t.column3, t.column4
FROM @tmp t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT column2, MIN(column3) [column3] FROM @tmp GROUP BY column2) v
    ON t.column2 = v.column2 AND t.column3 = v.column3
ORDER BY t.column3
```

This will get unique column2's with the oldest column3 and filter the table by those results sorting by column3

Answer (score 0):

I think `row_number()` is better ([Sql-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d359/6))

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4 
from (
  select column1, column2, column3, column4, 
         row_number() over (partition by column2 order by column3) rn
  from #tmp ) A
where rn=1
order by column3
```